# Sending a message to a user on mutliple lists

Tags: database, database-design

I am working with a team who is creating an iOs app for my company. The application we have sends out push notifications to our users. We have lists, which contains users in it. For eg. there is  favourite list, there is primary list, there is abc list....and they contain users. This helps us to send out messages to the user group through our lists.

Now, there are users who are present in more than one list. Say there is user xyz who is part of favourite and primary list. Now, when we send a message to both these groups, we don't want two push notifications to be received by user xyz.

So, what is the best way to implement this? Should we have a db table that stores user_id-message_id relation ship? If yes, wouldn't this require us to read the table each time we send the messages to multiple groups? Is there any other more efficient way to do this?

Your thoughts please.

Thanks.

Comment: seems like a question that ought to be tagged with database tags.

Comment: has nothing to do neither with ios nor with push-notifications :)

Comment: Agreed. I totally overlooked that. added db tags. removed ios tags. thanks

Comment: Yes, having a table with {MESSAGE_ID, USER_ID} key would definitely help, and with proper indexing that's shouldn't be a performance problem. However, if you are sending the message to all lists at once, you can just query DISTINCT user IDs from all the lists in a single query.